# How to get innerhtml of td and add text on button click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add * next to a td where the name of the row is written such as rate.
If an error occurs then I need to add * next to the relevant row.
Validation occurs on button click.

Someone else helped me with the code but I can't find the answer as to how to append * to the td. So if there is an error in any row i need to add * next to the relevant row but in the td with the text such as yield *

Thanks

```html
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#<%=form1.ClientID%>').submit(function (event) {
                //iterate over the rows
                $('.customValidationFrom').each(function (idx, obj) {
                    //get the input objects and values
                    var from = $(obj);
                    var to = $('#' + $(obj).attr("ID") + "To");
                    var fromVal = parseInt(from.val());
                    var toVal = parseInt(to.val());
                    //Cancel the submit
                    event.preventDefault();
                    //check range

                    if (fromVal > 100 || toVal > 100) {
                        var errorMessage = "<li id='" + from.attr('ID') + "Error'>The " + from.attr('data-name') + " field must be less than 100.</li>";
                        //Cancel the submit
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $('#errorMessageList').append(errorMessage);
                    
                    }

   
                    //Validate if both from and to inputs have values
                    if (from.val() && to.val()) {
                        if (fromVal > toVal) {
                          
                            //display error 
                            from.addClass('errorBorder');
                            to.addClass('errorBorder');

                            var errorMessage = "<li id='" + from.attr('ID') + "Error'>The " + from.attr('data-name') + " field must be less than the " + to.attr('data-name') + " field.</li>";
                            //Cancel the submit
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }
                        else {
                            //reset error
                            $('#errorMessageList li').remove();
                            from.removeClass('errorBorder');
                            to.removeClass('errorBorder');
                        }
                        $('#errorMessageList').append(errorMessage);

                    }

                });

            });
        });

       
    </script>
     
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <ul id="errorMessageList" class="errorText">

        </ul>

        <div>
            <table id="tbl1">
                <tr>
                    <td  class="style1">
                        rate
                    </td>
                    <td  >
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtRate" runat="server" class="customValidationFrom" data-name="rate from"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td >
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtRateTo" runat="server" class="customValidationTo" data-name="rate to"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                      <td  class="style1">
                        test</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtYield" runat="server" class="customValidationFrom" data-name="yield from"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                     <td >
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtYieldTo" runat="server" class="customValidationTo" data-name="yield from"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                     <td  class="style1">
                        yeld </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCal" runat="server" class="customValidationFrom" data-name="cal from"></asp:TextBox></td>
                      <td ">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCalTo" runat="server" class="customValidationTo" data-name="cal to"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('td').each(function() { 
    var text = $(this).text();
    if ( text == 'rate') {
        $(this).append('*')
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68me0obc/)

Comment: Sorry for the silly question but how do I add that piece of code inside the existing code? Also, I don't need to check if text=rate as the error can occur on any row. I just need to place the * next to the correct row but in the td of the text such as rate, yield etc

Comment: How are you defining an error? What is "an error on a row"?